# How to Redirect Powerbi click to a new web page

Tags: powerbi

How can I redirect a certain click onto the powerbi visualizations to a certain web page, let say I want to redirect a embedded report click onto a certain webpage how can I do that, does this kind of visualization possible in Powerbi if yes then How??

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot to describe what you expect where?

Comment: I mean to say that if I click on a certain visualization on a map then it should redirect me to a website whenever I click on the map visualization is that possible??

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, this is not supported in Power BI.

The only types of links available right now are `Back` and `Bookmark`.

[image: link types]

There's a [feature request for that](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/12902442-hyperlinks-in-power-bi-desktop) in the Power BI Ideas site, which you can vote for.

Comment: you mean to say that the redirection feature is not available in PowerBi yet?
How come its available in tableau?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean. I understand your frustration (and this is a feature I'd like as well). Tableau has been around for much longer than Power BI, so Microsoft is still catching-up on that space.

Comment: that's really frustrating..I was working in PowerBI for so long and haven't come across anything like this.. that's sad.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but if you are using Power BI Embedded reports, you can use the [PowerBI-Javascript](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript) to catch events from the tiles or reports and do some action like redirecting the user to a specific link.

```
var element = document.getElementById('reportContainer');
var report = powerbi.get(element);

report.on('dataSelected', function(event)
{
    console.log(event.detail.dataPoints[0].identity[0].equals);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this was available at the time, but my solution to this was creating a button that overlays the visualization. You can set the button background to transparent, then assign a fill for "hover" so that it's obvious that it's clickable. Then just set the web address as the action for the button.